# Blazor Menu keeping Menu Highlight (Active) for Child Detail Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have a table with list of items on a "List Page". Then when you select "View Detail" link on a row it should show the detail of that row item in a child "Detail Page".

- Home
- ListPage (I want to keep this Active)

  - DetailPage (This is not on the Menu since it's child page of ListPage)

**List Page**

| Id | Title | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My Item 1 | [View Detail](https://#) |
| 2 | My Item 2 | [View Detail](https://#) |

**Currently my Blazor Menu looks like this:**

| Menu |
| --- |
| [Home](https://#) |
| [List Page](https://#) |

```
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Loc["Home"]
        </NavLink>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ListPage">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Loc["ListPage"]
        </NavLink>
    </div>
```

**How do I keep the highlight of "List Page" on the menu when we go to the "View Detail" sub page in the table of List Page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `<NavLink...` does the this. It is the point of the `Match` parameter wich defaults to `NavLinkMatch.Prefix` if omitted. If your route is `@page "/ListPage"` then your child pages should use the route `@page "/ListPage/{SomeParameter}"` or similar. `NavLink` will then work as the route starts with `"/ListPage"`.

[NavLink Source Code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Routing/NavLink.cs,4241885b84240c12)

Comment: Your trick of putting the same page route with parameter works! Thank you!